# Notepad++ regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
{\i that}
```

and,

```
{\i it is this}
```

I cannot find the way to delete extra stuff from expressions so as to keep only at the above example the words "that" and "it is this".

Can you help me with the regular expression needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "{\i it is this}" | sed 's/{\\i //;s/}//'
```

Comment: and to delete parenthesis and the whole text inside two parentheses but without deleting text which is between different ( ) as in the following example? (Ex 20:12; Dt 5:16), the one without charity (Ex 21:17)

Answer (score 2):

Try each of the following two expressions *(the first one is more efficient if the text between `{` and `}` can't contain a `}` symbol)*:

```
\{\\i ([^}]+)\}
```

Or,

```
\{\\i (.+?)\}
```

and in both cases replace with `\1`.

Comment: There is no functional difference between those two expressions -- the second one will not react to nested {..} either. The real problems start when (1) there *may* be nested {..} or (2) the italic text may contain an escaped, literal `\}`. It might work for the OP, but this is something better handled with real code.

Comment: @Jongware Thank for your feedback, the problem is that the OP is using Notepad++, you are correct that regex are not suitable for nested structures in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Search : `\{\\i (.+)\}`

Replace with : \1

Comment: with your answer the search reaches to a second } ({\i  día}, y a la tiniebla llamó {\i  noche}   and I want to keep it to the first, what should I do?

Comment: You should add a questionmark `?` after the `+` quantifier to make it non-greedy, as in Sniffer's answer: `\{\\i (.+?)\}`